# Makefile use of $<

Tags: c, makefile

Can anyone explain why the use of $< in:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/release/%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(RELEASE_LINK.c) $< -c -o $@
```

iterates over both the .o files and .c files in pairs building an obj file from a c file, whereas $< in:

```
$(program_C_OBJS) : $(program_C_SRCS)
    $(RELEASE_LINK.c) $< -c -o $@
```

iterates over all the obj files but only ever pulls out the 1st dependency, i.e. the 1st c file

Is it possible in the 2nd example to modify such that the matching pairs of obj and c files are built as happens in the 1st example?

Comment: Why do you need the second rule at all? The first rule should already be sufficient for compiling all needed objects.

Comment: do you understand why the two snippets expand differently?

Comment: the problem i have is that the 1st example works, i.e. it builds all the object files from the c files but it is unspecific about which c files to build, i.e. it builds all of them. I want to be able to limit the c files built to only those in $(program_C_SRCS)

Comment: I am unclear why the target $@ expands out in both examples but the dependencies $< only expands out in the 1st no the 2nd example but the documentation suggests it should only ever return the 1st dependency?

Comment: See my answer. You limit which files make operates on by limiting the scope of what it needs to do to build the thing you asked it for. Not by creating rules for specific file mappings the way you were trying to do there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$<` variable doesn't "iterate" anything. It doesn't do anything but expand to the name of the first prerequisite of the target it is expanded in.

The first rule is a pattern rule. It applies to any files that need to be built that match that pattern.

The second rule (which almost certainly doesn't do anything even remotely like what you want unless those variables contain patterns) maps specific output files to specific input files (in your case presumably the limited set of input C files you want the rule to apply to).

The choice about what files get compiled during any given make run is determined by what files make is told to build and which of their dependencies make determines need to be updated to make that happen.

Comment: how might one overide the implicit building of object files from c files for a given set of c files, e.g. $(program_C_SRCS) in this instance? which is what i am trying to achieve here

Comment: Etan: your last paragraph is not correct.  An explicit rule with multiple targets is identical to writing that same rule multiple times with one target.  So `foo far faz : boo bar baz` is identical to writing three rules: `foo : boo bar baz`, `far : boo bar baz`, and `faz : boo bar baz`.  For implicit rules (pattern rules) the behavior is as you say: one invocation of the recipe should build all targets.  That's why each compilation in the OPs example builds the same source file; `$<` expands to the first file which is the same in each rule.

Comment: Hiett: your question as written doesn't appear to correlate very directly to the problem you're trying to solve.  I recommend you edit the question to more specifically describe your goal.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for the correction. I've removed that paragraph from my answer.

Comment: You override a default/fallback/etc. pattern rule with a more specific rule (or a rule that comes first if not using make 3.82 or newer). So in that sense your attempt seems to match your recently stated goal but your original question doesn't really match with that stated goal.

Answer (score 1):

From [GNU Make - 10.5.3 Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-g_t_0024_003c-967)

> $<
>       The name of the first prerequisite. If the target got its recipe from an implicit rule, this will be the first prerequisite added by the implicit rule

Depending on what you want to accomplish, there is also

> $?
>       The names of all the prerequisites that are newer than the target, with spaces between them.
>   $^
>       The names of all the prerequisites, with spaces between them

You can build a specific set of objects by stating them as dependencies to another target

```
target1: $(program_C_OBJS)
```

Now, when you call

```
make target1
```

`make` tries to create the dependencies for `target1`, which in turn can be built using your first rule, one by one. Of course, you can specify a command for target1 as well. This command will be executed as soon as its dependencies `$(program_C_OBJS)` are built.